# Intel Haxm Installation Error

Tags: windows-8.1

This is the error that I get every time I want to install Intel HAXM for Android.

[image: installation error]

I believe that my system can run this HAXM!

[image: system details]

I checked the Virtual Technology status on bios, 
it was already enabled.
Windows Hyper-V is enabled too!

so what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Hyper-V is enabled. It does not pass VT through to VMs or even the main operating system. Disable Hyper-V to use HAXM.

You might want to check out Virtual Box if you’re looking for desktop virtualization. It is much more feature-rich compared to Hyper-V and more suitable for most end-user use cases. I don’t use HAXM however, so I don’t know whether the two get along.

Comment: @Ramhound No, Hyper-V does not virtualize VT-x. VMware Workstation (and maybe other VMware products) are the only programs capable of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue because of my antivirus.
I uninstalled my antivirus, then HAXM installed properly after restarting.
I then re-installed Avast and HAXM works properly with virtual box and android emulators.
Antiviruses can start Hyper-V when windows starts and this does not allow HAXM to install.

Comment: It works. And now I am afraid of reinstalling Avast again.