# Can't install Intel HAXM with i5-6260U - apparently it doesn't support VT-x?

Tags: cpu, virtualization, android, vt-x

I'm trying to install [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) for improved virtual Android devices. Taken from the [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows), the hardware requirements are;

> Hardware Requirements:
>
> Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel®
>   64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality At least 1 GB of
>   available RAM

I downloaded the install archive and got an error when trying to install:

[image: The Error]

This confused me, as I was sure the i5-6260U supported VT-x - so I did a few quick checks:

[image: So I definitely have an i5-6260U]

So I definitely have an i5-6260U - I then checked the features of the CPU on Intel's website:

[image: Says it supports VT-x]

Their website suggests the CPU supports it. I also checked the BIOS to make sure it is enabled, which it is. There was also a file within the installation archive called `haxm_check.exe` so I ran this to make sure I wasn't on a wild goose chase, and this is what was returned:

[image: Oh poop]

So for some reason, my PC doesn't seem to think it supports VT-x, when (as far as I can tell) Intel suggest it does. Am I wrong in my assumptions, or do I have a problem somewhere?

Edit: Forgot to mention, I have tried installing HAXM both using the download from the Intel website and through the Android Studio SKD Manager.

Comment: Verify you have no other software that is set to use this extension, the majority if not ALL questions on this site talking about this exact problem, was caused by some other application already using the extension.  There is no technical reason you cannot run the software in question, which means, this is a pure configuration issue on your system.

Comment: You were right - Hyper-V was the culprit. Will mark accepted if you post as answer. Thanks

Comment: This exact question has been asked and answered before.  While I knew this was the case, didn't know what application it was, I can't really take credit for the answer alone since its just a combination of experience and knowledge.

Comment: I did a Google beforehand as this usually brings up all applicable SU questions and some more, however I did find other related Q's here when I searched specifically on SU. I was lazy, need coffee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intel Haxm Installation Error](http://superuser.com/questions/918676/intel-haxm-installation-error)

Answer (score 1):

if you have not disabled hyper-V you may need to do that first. to make sure Hyper-v was disabled correctly, please ensure that the computer reboots twice, in my case it rebooted only once and  i spent few hours trying to figure  our what went wrong. then i re -enabled it and disabled it again making sure the PC rebooted twice and then i had no problems installing Intel HAXM